# Find Intersection of Injective Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A=\left\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\right\}$ ($|A|=4$) and $B=\left\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5\right\}$ ($|B|=5$). How many injective functions $f:A\to B$ satisfy $f(a_1)=b_1$ or $f(a_2)=b_2$, inclusively.

We define $\alpha$ as the number of ways to define our first set and $\beta$ as the number of ways to define our second set.

For our first set, there are: 4 ways to define $f(a_2)$, 3 ways to define $f(a_3)$, and 2 ways to define $f(a_2)$ thus $|\alpha|=4⋅3⋅2$.

For our second set, there are: 4 ways to define $f(a_1)$, 3 ways to define $f(a_3)$, and 2 ways to define $f(a_4)$ thus $|\beta|=4⋅3⋅2$.

So, by the principle of inclusion and inclusion we have that $|α∪\beta| = |\alpha|+|\beta| - |\alpha\cap\beta|$.

My question: how does one obtain $|\alpha\cap\beta|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last set is when both $f(a_1)=b_1$ and $f(a_2)=b_2$. Thus there are only three choices for $f(a_3)$ and two choices for $f(a_4)$, and thus we have, in your notation, $|\alpha\cap \beta|=3\cdot 2=6$.